# Alchemy API - truncated-oversized-text-content

Tags: alchemyapi

getting the warning back of "truncated-oversized-text-content" when using Alchamy's entities API - does anyone know the character limit - I can't find on their support pages.

Comment: I should have probably just checked the number of characters in my truncated response - 51,000ish for reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text limit is 50kb, it's a bit hidden at the bottom of [this page](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/entity/textc.html#rtext).